# List of Appointments - Show Only Available Start Times

Tags: logic

I have a list of appointments for a day. There are 10 available appointments 15 minutes apart (I'm referring to each 15 minute appointment as a slot) and the list might look like this:

```
  1  Unavailable
  2  Unavailable
  3  Available
  4  Available
  5  Available
  6  Available
  7  Available
  8  Available
  9  Unavailable
  10 Unavailable
```

There are certain types of appointments that require a minimum number of slots. For example if the appointment type is "long" it needs 3 consecutive slots. So in the above example the possible combinations could be 3/4/5, 4/5/6, 5/6/7 and 6/7/8. I then need to keep 3/4/5 as available but swap 7/8 to Unavailable as the appointment cannot start at these times as there are not 3 consecutive available slots starting at these times.

I'm completely stumped as to the logic/rule I can use to implement here? I'm hoping there is something abstract that I can use and just feed in the number of slots required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a predicate $A(n)$ which says that slot $n$ is available.  Then you can define $L(n)=A(n)\wedge A(n+1) \wedge A(n+2)$ which says you can start a long appointment at time $n$